# How to handle IndirectLookUp datatype in External Datasource in Salesforce while consuming metadata

Tags: apex, lookup, externalobjects, mulesoft

In Salesforce External Datasource we are trying to Consuming Mule Application via Odata.
As part of this, client requirement is for one of the field datatype is IndirectLookup which links to Opportunity Table field. In Mule 4, while creating odata raml, i need to know how to handle IndirectLookup datatype. I tried with datatype as text it failed as below
***field type doesn't match. In Salesforce : "IndirectLookup". In data source : "Text"***

[image]

Mule Runtime:
<app.runtime>4.4.0-20220221</app.runtime>

Odata Dependency:

org.mule.modules mule-module-apikit-odata 2.2.0 mule-plugin

Please find the screenshot of the error steps

1. Freight field is Indirectlookup datatype

[image]

[image]
2. In Mule Sidee, metadata endpoint response below where Freight field is String. **Error Freight_c field doesn't match. In Salesforce : "IndirectLookup". In data source : "Text"**
[image]

[image]